# How to add "draw signature" to ninja forms

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, ninja-forms

I was wondering if anyone knows an easy way to add the ability to draw your signature on a ninja form field. Perhaps using the html field of it?

Answer (score 1):

You might find it easiest to use [this](https://www.approveme.com/ninja-forms-signature-contract-automation/) instead of a custom solution.